# Keras model with second to last sigmoid activated Conv1D layer followed by globalMaxPool outputs values outside [0,1]. Why?

Tags: deep-learning, classification, keras, convolutional-neural-network

I am trying to train a binary classifier. It is a residual network with skip layers etc. but ultimately, the bottom two layers are a 1D convolution with sigmoid activation followed by a global max pool afterwards. I believed this should output predictions between 0 and 1.

In fact, I've trained a very similar model previously and it was working as expected but then I decided to change the way I preprocess input data and changed a few minor aspects like kernel size etc. and now when I call model.predict(inputs) I am getting a very broad range of values - at least between [-20,20]. I really don't see why, can anyone look at my model and potentially help me understand where I've gone wrong?

Here is a json string that should allow you to load my model with
`model = model_from_json(json_string)`. Note that the final two layers are called 'conv_final' (conv1D with sigmoid activation) and 'output' (global max pooling)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3qywmcho5tldurr/final_model.json?dl=0